# How to show the following $\alpha x − \beta x^2 - \dfrac{\alpha^2}{4\beta} \leq 0$

Tags: inequality, polynomials

I would like to show that the following is true, for all $\alpha \geq 0 , \beta> 0$, we have that:

$$\alpha x − \beta x^2 - \dfrac{\alpha^2}{4\beta} \leq 0, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$

Is there a way to prove this result?

Attempt:

$$ 0\leq \beta x^2 - \alpha x +  \dfrac{\alpha^2}{4\beta} , \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$

We want to show that the polynomial on the right hand side only has imaginary roots

Dividing $\beta$ across, yields:

$$ 0\leq  x^2 - \dfrac{\alpha}{\beta} x +  \dfrac{\alpha^2}{4\beta^2} , \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$

Then using quadratic formula:

$$\dfrac{1}{2}\left[\dfrac{\alpha}{\beta} \pm \sqrt{\dfrac{4\alpha^2}{4\beta^2} - (4)\dfrac{\alpha^2}{4\beta^2}}\right]$$

which is equal to $$\dfrac{1}{2}\left[\dfrac{\alpha}{\beta}\right]$$

It seems that the roots are real. Therefore this inequality cannot hold true. Can anyone provide assistance?

Comment: `We want to show that the polynomial on the right hand side only has imaginary roots` No, for the *non*-strict inequality all you need to show is that it does not have $2$ *distinct* real roots.

Comment: @dxiv Okay I originally made a mistake in the quadratic formula. Now it is clear to me why the inequality holds true. But I will still take answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
-\beta x^{2}+\alpha x-\dfrac{\alpha^{2}}{4\beta}&=-\beta\left(x-\dfrac{\alpha}{2\beta}\right)^{2}+\beta\cdot\dfrac{\alpha^{2}}{4\beta^{2}}-\dfrac{\alpha^{2}}{4\beta}\\
&=-\beta\left(x-\dfrac{\alpha}{2\beta}\right)^{2}\\
&\leq 0.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Using the famous inequality: $2AB \le A^2+B^2$ with $A = x\sqrt{\beta}, B = \dfrac{\alpha}{2\sqrt{\beta}}$ the conclusion follows.

Answer (score 0):

Just:  $\alpha x − \beta x^2 - \dfrac{\alpha^2}{4\beta} =\dfrac{1}{4 \beta}\big(4\alpha\beta x − 4\beta^2 x^2 - \alpha^2\big) = -\, \dfrac{1}{4 \beta}\big(2\beta x - \alpha\big)^2\leq 0\,$.

Answer (score 0):

By your work we need to prove that:
$$ x^2 - \dfrac{\alpha}{\beta} x +  \dfrac{\alpha^2}{4\beta^2}\geq0,$$
which is $$\left(x-\frac{\alpha}{2\beta}\right)^2\geq0,$$ which is obvious.